# Ubuntu 22 Firefox tab color

Tags: 22.04, color-management, tabs

My computer upgraded from Ubuntu 20 to 22 last night. now the tabs are all the same color when i go on the internet, the color scheme barely highlights the active tab, they are all just gray with black text. at best there is a faint squire box around the active tab.

Is there a way I can change the background color of the active tab or something so I can actually identify witch one is currently active without squinting?

The Firefox help says I have Firefox version 104.0 installed and the Ubuntu help about says Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I don't really care what color the tabs are, just as long as there is a clear difference between active tabs and inactive tabs.

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/1653533/how-to-switch-back-to-firefox-old-style-of-tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox go to the hamburger (3 parallel lines) icon menu and select `Add-ons and Themes`.

This will open a tab allowing you to manage your themes from which you can see what is currently enabled or select from various listed options for you t try at will. If those don't match your expectations, scroll down to the bottom and select `Find more themes`.

[image]

Comment: many thanks, interestingly most of the themes have the same problem yet the Alpenglow one has a white background for the selected tab. im sure i will get used to pink in the end.